# WPF ViewModel and View

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, binding

I've been programming in WPF for a while now coming from Windows Forms. Because of this I've always been linking my View and ViewModel directly together by giving my controls in the View a name and use that name in the ViewModel to update my View.

Now I did some searching and found out that there is something called MVVM. I've been studying it for a week now and tried to make my application 'better'.

First, I started using binding with Dependency Properties like this:

```
Public Shared SelKlantProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelKlant", GetType(String), GetType(MainWindow))
Public Property SelKlant As String
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(SelKlantProperty), String)
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        SetValue(SelKlantProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property
```

I now have about 50 Properties made like that and my code is getting big pretty fast of those. Also my ClassDiagram is filled with the Fields of the `Public Shared DependencyProperty` and Properties of the `Public Property`.

I'm wondering, is there an easier or much better way to bind View and ViewModel? Most of the `Properties` I use are to put `Text` in `TextBoxes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create dependency properties for your view model properties - regular properties will suffice. You will however have to use dependency properties if you're going to bind *to* that property (for example, `TextBox.Text` is a dependency property - you wouldn't be able to bind to it if it wasn't). You can keep your properties as they were - just make sure you implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Dependency properties have other uses other than just for data binding, but I won't elaborate as it's a very large subject and you can find in other resources. Other than that, you can read more on how to implement the MVVM pattern [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx). This page also includes examples where you can see that the viewmodel does not need to have any dependency properties defined.

Comment: But if have this code in my xaml: `<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SelKlant}"/>`. If I only have the `Property`, if I type in the TextBox or set the property, it won't link to code or view. How do I do that then without creating dependency properties?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, simple properties which implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` should suffice. Have a look at the example I linked to for more details.

Comment: Tnx for the link. I'll do some reading. Does it also explain when to use dependency properties?

Comment: The most common case where you'd want to use a dependency property is when you want to use binding where the property is *the target for that binding*. A quick Google search on the subject will yield plenty of information.

Comment: DependencyProperties are *not* "target properties."  They are simply properties with a backing store tightly integrated into the binding system.  That there are read-only dependency properties should be enough to prove that fact.

Comment: @Will I never said dependency properties are target properties. What I said was that you're required to use dependency properties when you want to bind to that property (having the dependency property as the target). There are plenty of other reasons to use dependency properties which I didn't mention as I didn't think they should be covered by the scope of the question.

Comment: @AdiLester: *Dependency properties are for the target properties (TextBox.Text in your case) and not the source properties (view model properties such as SelKlant)*  Seems pretty clear to me :/  This statement is not true.  A fix would be nice.